# Landau levels in symmetric gauge, what is the constraint on the quantum numbers?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, magnetic-fields, schroedinger-equation, linear-algebra

After solving the Schrödinger equation for the charged particle in a constant and homogeneous magnetic field, using the symmetric gauge $\vec{A} = \frac{B}{2} (-y, x, 0)$, we could find the Landau energy levels as the following expression (notice the absolute values, depending on the particle's charge: $q \gtrless 0$):
$$\tag{1}
E_{n m} = (2 n + |m| + 1) \hbar |\omega| + m \hbar \omega,
$$
where $\omega = - q B / 2 m$ is the Larmor angular frequency (half the *cyclotron* angular frequency $\omega_c = - q B/m$), $n = 0, 1, 2, \dots, \infty$ is the main quantum number (the *degree* of the Laguerre polynomials), and $m = 0, \pm 1, \pm 2, \pm 3, \dots$ is the *magnetic* quantum number.  The Hamiltonian eigenfunctions are the following (using $u = \sqrt{m |\omega|/\hbar} \: r$):
$$\tag{2}
\psi_{n m}(r, \varphi) = N \, u^{|m|} \, L_n^{|m|}(u^2) \, e^{- u^2 / 2} \, \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \, e^{i m \varphi}.
$$
During the solving process, I found the usual Laguerre polynomials equation in the following shape, with $\xi \equiv u^2$:
$$\tag{3}
\xi \frac{d^2 L}{d \xi^2} + (|m| + 1 - \xi) \frac{d L}{d \xi} + n L = 0,
$$
with (this give the formula (1))
$$\tag{4}
n = \frac{1}{2} \Bigl( \frac{E - m \hbar \omega}{\hbar |\omega|} - |m| - 1 \Bigr).
$$
My issue is about the maximal value of $|m|$.  Some sources say that the magnetic quantum number is constraint: $|m| = 0, 1, 2, \dots$ up to $|m|_{max} = n$, a bit like for the Hydrogen atom which imposes $|m|_{max} = n - 1$ (sorry, I can't find back these sources, so I can't give them here).  Searching the internet, I'm unable to find any reliable source that solves the Landau levels in the symmetric gauge up to the formula (1).  I don't see why there should be a maximal value for $|m|$.  So is there a reason why $|m|_{max} = n$ (or another constraint)?

I could justify this constraint only if I write instead (this is just an arbitrary change of notation)
$$\tag{5}
\xi \frac{d^2 L}{d \xi^2} + (|m| + 1 - \xi) \frac{d L}{d \xi} + (\tilde{n} - |m|) L = 0,
$$
where
$$\tag{6}
n = \tilde{n} - |m| = \frac{1}{2} \Bigl( \frac{E - m \hbar \omega}{\hbar |\omega|} - |m| - 1 \Bigr).
$$
Then, this give a modified energy levels formula (notice the sign change, relative to (1)):
$$\tag{7}
E_{n m} = (2 \tilde{n} - |m| + 1) \hbar |\omega| + m \hbar \omega.
$$
Since $n = \tilde{n} - |m| \ge 0$ is the *degree* of the Laguerre polynomials in equation (5), this implies that $|m| \le \tilde{n}$.  The eigenfunctions (2) would then have to be modified with the Laguerre functions $L_{\tilde{n} - |m|}^{|m| \,\le\, \tilde{n}}$, which is a bit more complicated than just $L_n^{|m|}$ without any limit to $|m|$.

The change of (3) to (5) is arbitrary.  So is there really some arbitrariness in defining the Landau energy levels in the symmetric gauge?

I would like to see a good paper that shows in details the solution that give (1) (or (7)?).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have looked at this problem in the context of the Weyl equation. Below is a word-for-word  extract from my notes, so it is not *exactly* what you want, but the square of the Weyl operator is the Schroedinger equation and my last paragraph relates to the physical meaning of the ranges of various integers.  This interpretation came from numerically plotting the wavefunctions rather than by analytic reasoning.

---

Consider the motion of  a massless, right-handed, Weyl fermion with positive charge $e$ in a magnetic field ${\bf B}= -B \hat{\bf z}$. The downward direction of the field has been  chosen so that the particle orbits in an anticlockwise direction about the $z$ axis. The vector potential is therefore  ${\bf A}= (By/2,-Bx/2,0)$.

The Weyl Hamiltonian is
$$
H= -i{\boldsymbol \sigma}\cdot (\partial -ie{\bf A}),
$$
and
$$
H^2 = {\mathbb I}\left(- \nabla^2 + \frac{e^2B^2}{4} r^2 +eBL_3 +k_3^2\right) + eB\sigma_3.
$$
Here $L_3= -i(x\partial_y-y\partial x)=-i\partial_\theta$ is the canonical (but not kinetic) angular momentum.
The energy eigenvalues for the expression in brackets is
$$
E^2_{n,l} = eB\left\{2n+|l|+l+ 1\right\}+k^2_3
$$
with eigenfunctions
$$
\varphi_{n,l}(r,\phi) =\left(\frac{eB}{2}\right)^{(|l|+1)/2} \sqrt{\frac{n!}{(n+|l|)!}} r^{|l|}\exp\left(-\frac{eBr^2}{4}\right) L^{|l|}_n\left(\frac{eBr^2}{2}\right) e^{il\theta}.
$$
Here $L^{|l|}_n(x)$ is the degree-$n$ associated Laguerre polynomial
$$
L^{|l|}_n(x) = \frac{x^{-|l|}}{n!} e^x \frac{d^n}{dx^n} (e^{-x} x^{n+|l|})
$$
with the property that
$$
\int_0^\infty x^{\alpha} e^{-x} L^\alpha_n(x)L^\alpha_m(x) dx = \frac{(n+\alpha)!}{n!} \delta_{nm}.
$$
There is a generating function
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty L_n^k(x) t^n =(1-t)^{-k-1} \exp\left\{-\frac{ xt}{(1-t)}\right\}
$$
And an addition formula
$$
\exp{\left(x y e^{i \phi}\right)} L_n\left(x^2 + y^2 - 2 x y
\cos{\phi}\right)  = \sum_{k = 0}^\infty \left(x y e^{i\phi}\right)^{(k - n)}
\frac{n!}{k!} L_n^{(k - n)}\left(x^2\right) L_n^{(k - n)}\left(y^2\right). 
$$

For our eigenfunctions both   $n$ and $l$ are integers.
When $n=0$  and $l>0$, the  wavefunction corresponds to classical  particle describing a circle with radius
$$
R_l=\sqrt{\frac{2l}{eB}}
$$
with the origin as its centre. If we  decrease $l$ while staying in the same Landau level  (*i.e.*  by increasing $n$ so  as to keep $E^2_{n,l}$ fixed)  the classical circular orbit  keeps the same radius but its centre moves away from the origin and is smeared-out in $\theta$ over the full  $2\pi$.  When $l=0$ the circle passes through the origin. For $l$ negative, the energy no longer depends on $l$ and the Landau level keeps $n$ fixed while  $l$ continues to decrease.  The classical  orbit still has the original radius, but no longer encloses  the origin.

The familiar lowest-Landau-level state with the same radius circular wavefunction  corresponds to $n=0$ and $l=-|l|$.

Comment: What is $k_3$ here? Did you just use the fact that the Hamiltonian commutes with $p_z$ to only look at mutual $p_z$ eigenstates or is it something else?

Comment: Sorry! $k_3$ is the momentum of the Weyl particle in the $z$ direction. It is probably irrelevent for you problem. It's only there because I do not have time to edit my notes which are related to my old paper arXiv:1507.01807

Comment: So are you saying that your $l$ doesn't have any constraint on its value, i.e $|l| = 0, 2, 3, \dots, \infty$, independently of the values of $n$?  Is that it?

Comment: Probably! It's a long time since I wrote this stuff and I have slept since then.... Plotting the wavefunctions and remembering that fixed $l$ means totally uncertain $\theta$ was how I came to the stated conclusions.